# Blender noise during paint in Texture paint mode

Tags: texture-painting, artifacts

I have weird problem. During paint in texture paint mode after paint the color is not filled but have any "noise". Like on the image:
[image]

Comment: @MrZak Yes, I do. If You could make answer then I will mark it.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In texture painting, brush can have a texture [assigned to it as a pattern](https://www.blender.org/manual/de/sculpt_paint/painting/texture_paint/options.html#texture). When it is, the pattern will be applied to every stroke done with the brush (appearence will depend on settings of the brush mapping etc.):

[image: screenshot of patterns while painting in texture Paint]

See more about [how to assign a texture to the brush and paint with it](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32801/how-do-i-texture-paint-with-realistic-textures).

If you want to continue drawing with solid color, unlink that texture in brush settings by pressing X button next to its name. For more about that refer to [Users (Sharing)](https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/data_blocks.html#users-sharing) and [Removing data-blocks](https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/data_blocks.html#removing-data-blocks) in manual.

Answer (score 0):

from your screenshot , you have the blend mode  set to color,

this mode  changes the hue and saturation of your image to the hue and saturation of your solid color but leaves luminosity alone, the result apprears as noise in this case.
you may want to change the blend mode to mix to paint  with your solid color