# Vertex Paint - creating gradient from selected vertices?

Tags: vertex-paint

So what I want to create vertex paint gradient from selected edge loops like this:

[image]

In this picture I did with brush, but I have some bigger models so it could be tedious. I know you can do this in weight paint like this:

[image]

So maybe a script that converts weight paint into vertex paint would be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

To make the gradient as the result of the vertex paint assign a texture as a pattern to the brush or use weight paint and convert it into the vertex painted colors.

#### Painting vertex colors with brush pattern

1. In Edit mode select faces which you'd like to be affected by Vertex paint. Go to Vertex Paint mode and enable the *Face Selection Masking* option to make the selected faces be the only ones affected.
2. In the brush settings, *Texture* rollout [assign texture](https://www.blender.org/manual/ru/sculpt_paint/painting/vertex_paint/options.html#texture) with desired effect. If the resulted vertex colors should be gradient-like, procedural texture of the *Blend* type will be good enough.
3. Choose *Stencil* option to paint with texture in the [same way as in Texture Painting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32801/how-do-i-texture-paint-with-realistic-textures). Move it in the 3D Viewport with <kbd>RMB</kbd> to set up painting as desired.

   [image: GIF vertex painting with brush pattern]

#### Converting Weight Paint into desired vertex colors

There's an [addon for converting weight paint into vertex colors and vice versa](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?290390-Weights-to-Vertex-Colors-addon).

1. After [activating it](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/installing-an-addon), create a weight paint to be converted. Use *Weight Gradient*, *Quantize* tools etc. from the *Toolshelf* to create the final result.
2. In the Vertex Colors mode, 3d Viewport header find and run *Paint* > *WeightToVertexColor*.

Answer (score 1):

This script lets you color the vertices associated with any selected geometry.

```
import bpy
import random


def set_verts_colors(new_color):

    # must switch to Object Mode briefly to get the new set of selected elements
    # and then change the vertex_color layer
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    obj = bpy.context.active_object

    mesh = obj.data
    color_layer = mesh.vertex_colors.active  
    selected = set(v.index for v in obj.data.vertices if v.select)

    i = 0
    for poly in mesh.polygons:
        for loop_index in poly.loop_indices:
            vidx = mesh.loops[loop_index].vertex_index            
            if vidx in selected:
                color_layer.data[i].color = new_color
            i += 1

    # set to vertex paint mode to see the result
    # bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='VERTEX_PAINT')
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')


set_verts_colors(new_color=(1,0.5,0.6))
```

Note: there is currently no mechanism to select verts or edges individually while in Vertex Paint mode, but you can view Vertex colors while in Edit Mode.

[image]

### as an Add-on

An Add-on might already exist that does this either as a feature, or sole purpose - If so, I couldn't find it. Below you'll find the same script converted into an add-on (installation just like any other add-on).

[code](https://github.com/zeffii/set_arbitrary_vcols) hosted on GitHub, or convenient [download link](https://github.com/zeffii/set_arbitrary_vcols/archive/master.zip)

trigger via `Spacebar -> Set VCols of any Geometry`, or add a shortcut yourself.

[image]

press escape to leave the VCols unchanged, press OK to set them with the picked Color.

[image]

becomes

[image]